# Placing a link in windows 8 metro style app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

How can I link my web address www.facebook.com to my hyperlink button.and that should load in my app page.

Comment: Second sentence seem to conflict with the first one. Maybe it's not needed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only load a web page inside a `WebView` control. Put it somewhere on your page first:

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView" />
```

In the click event handler of your `Hyperlink` load the page into this `WebView`:

```
private void Hyperlink_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.facebook.com"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start("http://facebook.com"); that will load the default browser at facebook.com  is this what you require ?

how about the launcher class ?  You can use the Launcher class to launch a document in the default handler,  i.e load a website with the default browser, from what i understand you cant just create a process.

```
async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Path to the file in the app package to launch
   string imageFile = @"images\test.png";

   var file = wait Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);

   if (file != null)
   {
      // Launch the retrieved file
      var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

      if (success)
      {
         // File launched
      }
      else
      {
         // File launch failed
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Could not find file
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to place all icons of social networking websites when user clicks on fb icon it should load http://facebook.com and i am doing it in c# and xaml

Comment: does you want it to load in the users default browser or create some kind of web view ?

Comment: it should load in my app page not in the users web page or default browser